# Purpose of passing an object to Class which implements runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

There are 3 classes.

1. `CallMe` The basic class which prints the message
2. `Caller` Implements `Runnable` and it gets the object from the main class `Synch`
3. `Synch` The main class which creates the object for `CallMe` and passes the same to class `Caller` class and starts the thread.

**Question**: 
In the `Synch` class, what is the need to pass the object to the class `Caller`?        When I tried a call to the class `Caller` without the object of `CallMe` the compiler  throws a `NullPointerException`. Could you please provide any reasons for this behaviour.

eg : `Caller ob1 = new Caller("Hello");  // calling without an object of class "CallMe"`

Below is the working code for reference.

```
public class CallMe {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    CallMe target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller(CallMe targ, String s) {
        target = targ;
        msg = s;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        target.call(msg);
    }
}

class Synch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CallMe target = new CallMe();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Hello");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "World");
        // wait for threads to end
        try {
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler throws a NullPointerException because of the line

```
target.call(msg)
```

If you pass null to the Caller constructor, then the instance variable target gets set to null, and you're calling a method on a null reference, hence NullPointerException.

As for why you need to have both a 'Caller' and a 'CallMe' class, it's just a matter of style. The idea is to create a Runnable 'wrapper class' for whatever business logic your code may include. That way threading is not tied into the core of your project.

Answer (score 0):

> Caller ob1 = new Caller("Hello");

Firstly, this would be a compile-time error as you don't have a `Caller` constructor that only takes a string as argument.

> When I tired a call to the class "Caller" without the object of "CallMe" the compiler throws null pointer exception

I assume you meant to have created caller as follows:

```
Caller ob1 = new Caller(null, "Hello");
```

If so, the NPE is thrown by your run method which is automatically called by the `thread.start()` call you have in your `Caller` constructor. It seems the job of `Caller` is use to run the `CallMe` function in a separate thread and so the `CallMe` objects passed to it must be non-null values. The reason for NPE is absence of a valid `CallMe` object in your case.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The CallMe object *target* inside Caller is not initialized and therefore has `null` value until you call the constructor Caller(target, "XXX") to initialize it. You always get the `null pointer exception` when the object you call on has the value `null`.

If you use Caller("XXX") instead without passing in a CallMe object, `target` inside Caller object will by no means be initialized.